# How do I restore the operating system using Acronis?

Tags: hard-drive, vmware, clone, acronis-trueimage

I have made a backup using Acronis 2010. And I've tested it on vmware.
And I'm having problems booting up the dual boot vm. After restoring from the .tib file. What do I do?What other software that can image the os can you recommend that is easier to use than Acronis.

Comment: Why do you have a dual-boot VM rather than two separate VMs?

Comment: "What other software that can image the os can you recommend that is easier to use than Acronis."

Been using Acronis since version 6, its as easy as any image software, it can be as complicated as you want, but default settings are the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off what OS images are you trying to dual boot.  You have to use different processes for different OS.  For instance with Linux and Windows it is typically best install Windows then Linux and to use the GRUB boot manager.  Different process for Linux Linux or Windows Windows.  Here is a very good site on the subject:

http://apcmag.com/how_to_dual_boot_windows_xp_and_linux_xp_installed_first.htm

As far as an Acronis alternative, I have been using Norton Ghost for the past 5 years with good success.  I have also used DriveSnapShot but I like Ghost better.